# How to write vector tiles gerneated by mapnik into mbtiles file in Javascript/Python?

Tags: vector-tiles

I am trying to write a JavaScirpt/Python script to pre-seed vector tiles. My plan is to gather data from a PostGIS database and generate tiles with mapnik, but I don't know how to finally save them into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Javascript, [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) to generate mbtiles from GeoJSON, which can be easily generated from PostGIS.